# Animating "depth" in SVG

Tags: animation, svg

As far as I'm aware, there isn't any particular way of doing depth in SVG. Elements are drawn in the order they appear, so if something needs to go behind something else, it *must* be earlier in the document.

I'm trying to create an animation, which for simplicity let's say it's the Earth orbiting the Sun. Doing this from above would be easy enough, just follow a circular path. However I want to have it viewed from a quite shallow angle, so the Earth would be going behind the Sun.

My current idea is to have two Earths, one before and one after the Sun. Something like...

```
<use xlink:href="#earth" />
<use xlink:href="#sun" />
<use xlink:href="#earth" />
```

Then I animate the two Earths, one going right-to-left and the other left-to-right, and alternating their visibility to only appear half the time. With the appropriate timing, this results in a single Earth being seen to orbit the Sun.

Honestly I quite like this idea, but I'm just wondering if anyone knows of a better way to do this kind of "3D-like" thing.

Answer (score 2):

Why have two of the complicated things? It would be much easier to have two suns.  Animate your earth on a continuous elliptical path.  Then switch between your two suns at the right times.

Comment: ...or even let the bottom layer sun be and only switch the top layer on and off.

Comment: I love your lateral thinking. Very nice. Unfortunately it won't work in my case because the example I gave is simplified. Having two planets, for example, wouldn't work with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can create two sibling `<g>` elements (call them `topLayer` / `bottomLayer` or alike), and then move your *planet* elements from one layer to another without duplicating them

Comment: I have experimented with this option, but I'm trying to use just animation definitions rather than bringing JavaScript into the mix, if possible. Maybe that's a silly self-imposed restriction and I *should* use scripting to help... Maybe I can even combine the two and have it switch the planet to the other layer when the animation end event fires... Lots of options, it turns out!